# iPad app crashes on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an app which seems to work fine in debug mode, but now it's live in the app store it crashes every time. I have managed to find a crash log, which shows the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3238329e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a22e97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x3451837c +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436
3   UIKit                           0x3435a58e -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 38
4   UIKit                           0x341e379c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x3418bc34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
6   UIKit                           0x3418b6c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x3418b116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
8   GraphicsServices                0x35e9659e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
9   GraphicsServices                0x35e961ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3235816e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32358112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
12  CoreFoundation                  0x32356f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
13  CoreFoundation                  0x322c9eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
14  CoreFoundation                  0x322c9d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  UIKit                           0x341e2480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
16  UIKit                           0x341df2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

Does anyone know what this means? I really need to submit an update for this app quickly so I need to fix it.

Comment: looks like it is happening in code you don't own... so my guess is that you have something configured incorrectly, change the name of your storyboard without changing the info.plist or something to that effect seems most likely here.

Comment: probably the problem is the name in the storyboard, you wanted to load; check the typo.

Comment: Try cleaning, uninstalling, and re-rerunning your debug build.  You might find that it crashes as well.  I bet an old copy of the storyboard is hanging around.  This method will throw an exception if it can't find the storyboard.  In your case, it seems that it can't find the main storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One great place to start is this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

It will show you how to read your crash log.

For instance EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) means:

```
The exception code is a SIGABRT. Usually, a SIGABRT exception is raised when an object receives an unimplemented message. Or to put it in simpler terms, there’s a call for a nonexistent method on an object.
```

This should give you a hint as to what the problem is.  It's not in your code as you can see that your classes are not called in the list to the right.

I would also say that if it doesn't work in the app store you might make sure that it works for all languages on Ad-Hoc.  Maybe something is missing from your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check the storyboard names. Make sure you have a main storyboard selected for ipad and that the name matches.

Comment: The storyboard names do seem to match. The only thing I've changed in this update is to add localization for French and Spanish (previously the app was English-only). Not sure if this could impact on it.

It's very difficult to test, since it works in debug mode and even in ad hoc release builds, just not in the app store.